# Sony PSM SDK's 2D game engine

Tags: 2d, mobile

I have started with the Sony PSM SDK this week, I'm interested in creating a little 2D game and have been reading through the web about a so called "2D game engine" integrated into the SDK.

Some information I read suggested that it was added on January 2012, but I have been going through the documentation and haven't been able to find any reference to it.

Does anybody know if they finally introduced the 2D game engine for the PSM SDK?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we do not support "does software X support feature Y" questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the documentation and navigate to:
**PlayStation(R)Mobile SDK -> Related Pages -> User Guide -> GameEngine2D**

There are also examples for Physics2D, In-App purchasing, On Screen Controller etc.

---

*You might be in the wrong documents. 
The documentation installed under this path for me: C:/Users/Public/Documents/PSM/doc/en/index.html*

Comment: Thans a lot for the information